# SELECT row that has MAX date

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to select the ROW that has the latest date. I do not seem to be able to select both the ID and Released.

T.Released = MAX (T.Released) does not work for me . I am using MS SQL

```
SELECT ID , Released
FROM ( SELECT [id]   
      ,[Released]       
  FROM [dbo].[PressReleases]
  where id   in 
    (
      .....
    ) ) as T

Where T.Released = MAX (T.Released)

id  Released
3   2016-05-26 19:30:41.100
214 2016-07-04 10:10:32.500
244 2017-01-20 12:20:29.900
247 2017-03-09 15:50:38.600
235 2017-06-01 18:10:38.900
237 NULL
```

Comment: It is MS SQL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the MAX Released-Date in a subquery.

```
SELECT [id]   
      ,[Released]       
  FROM [dbo].[PressReleases]
 WHERE Released = ( 
                     SELECT MAX(Released)
                       FROM [dbo].[PressReleases]
                       -- Select here your T Table with the Where Conditions
                  )
```

Comment: Yes that would work for me as the Released dates are always unique. Maybe not the best way of doing it but it works for me

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the column in your subquery;

```
SELECT ID , Released
FROM ( SELECT [id]   
      ,[Released]       
  FROM [dbo].[PressReleases]
  where id   in 
    (
      .....
    ) ) as T    
Where T.Released = MAX (T.Released)
```

Or you can just do;

```
SELECT ID , Released
FROM [dbo].[PressReleases]
  where id   in 
    (
      .....
    )
AND T.Released = (SELECT MAX (Released) FROM dbo.PressReleases)
```

Comment: Hello I would like the MAX released from T not from dbo.PressReleases as the maybe more releases but I just want the MAX result in T. Thanks you very much for your reply